# Connecting the board to the player objects

Tags: python

Having coded for the players for my boardgame, I am facing difficulties with creating the board and connectying it to the players.

The board is a list containig 10 slots, where each slot is a string with a hidden from the player letter (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,I,J,K). The letter is only known to the owner of the slot.

At the beggining of the game all players are placed in the very first slot

Every time the player(object) throws a dice, it moves according to the dice.

Code for the players(no problem here)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Player: 
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    coins: int
    slot: int
    def full_info(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname} {self.coins} {self.slot}"

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls) -> 'Player':
        return cls(
            firstname=input("Please enter your first name:"),
            lastname=input("Please enter your second name: "),
            coins=100,
            slot= 0)   
player1 = Player.from_user_input()
Player(firstname='', lastname='', coins=100, slot= 0)
player2 = Player.from_user_input()
Player(firstname='', lastname='', coins=100, slot= 0)


playersingame = [player1, player2]
print(playersingame)
```

The board is printing only the emtpty slots, it does not show players in the slot.

In the attributes of my players I put slot= 0, when I run the code it does not show that.

````
board = [None] *10
print(board)
board.insert(0, player1)
board.insert(0, player2)
print(board)```
````

Comment: Explain "not working". What happens, what should happen? If there are error messages show them as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher When I print the board, the output shows that all of the slots are empty. Although I put slot= 0 in the attributes of my players, it does not print the players in slot.

Comment: 1. What's the use of the 2 "Player(firstname='', lastname='', coins=100, slot= 0)" statements ? 2. When I run your code it doesn't show the board as empty, though it certainly doesn't print what you probably expected (speaking about which, please state CLEARLY what your expected output is).

Comment: @Swifty, the first name, last name and coins are attribtutes to the player. The expected output is, all players in the first slot. After than an option for the players to roll the dice. (press x to roll the dice) I am going to place the code for dice here

Comment: if str(input("Please enter X to roll the dice")) == "x" or "X":
import random
print("You rolled",random.randint(1,6))

PS. After that I expect the player1 to move forwards according to the dice.

Comment: Ok then; inserting is not a good idea, since it lengthens your list; do something like in Cristian's answer, but use a collection to allow several players to occupy the same slot. About your dice roll, assign the random number to a variable before printing it!

Comment: @Swifty, Thank you so much, could you please demonstrate how the code would look like? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here; I modified the player creation a little too.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Player: 
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    coins: int
    slot: int
    def full_info(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname} {self.coins} {self.slot}"

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls) -> 'Player':
        return cls(
            firstname=input("Please enter your first name:"),
            lastname=input("Please enter your second name: "),
            coins=100,
            slot= 0)

# Creating players
minplayer, maxplayer, n = 2, 5, -1
while not(minplayer <= n <= maxplayer):
    n = int(input(f"Please choose a number of players between {minplayer} and {maxplayer}: "))
playersingame = []
for i in range(n):
    playersingame.append(Player.from_user_input())


print([player.full_info() for player in playersingame])

board = [[] for i in range(10)]
print(board)

for player in playersingame:
    board[player.slot].append(player)

print(board)
```

Example:

```
Please choose a number of players between 2 and 5: 3

Please enter your first name:Tom

Please enter your second name: Bombadil

Please enter your first name:Frodo

Please enter your second name: Baggins

Please enter your first name:Saruman

Please enter your second name: ZeWhite
['Tom Bombadil 100 0', 'Frodo Baggins 100 0', 'Saruman ZeWhite 100 0']
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[Player(firstname='Tom', lastname='Bombadil', coins=100, slot=0), Player(firstname='Frodo', lastname='Baggins', coins=100, slot=0), Player(firstname='Saruman', lastname='ZeWhite', coins=100, slot=0)], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Here's code for one round (you can wrap it in a loop afterwards to implement the full game):

```
# Playing a round
import random

for player in playersingame:
    input(f"{player.firstname} {player.lastname}, please press enter to roll your die...")
    die = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f"You take {die} step{'s'*(die>1)} forward")
    board[player.slot].remove(player)
    player.slot += die
    board[player.slot].append(player)
    
print(board)
```

Example:

```
Tom Bombadil, please press enter to roll your die...
You take 3 steps forward

Frodo Baggins, please press enter to roll your die...
You take 1 step forward

Saruman ZeWhite, please press enter to roll your die...
You take 4 steps forward
[[], [Player(firstname='Frodo', lastname='Baggins', coins=100, slot=1)], [], [Player(firstname='Tom', lastname='Bombadil', coins=100, slot=3)], [Player(firstname='Saruman', lastname='ZeWhite', coins=100, slot=4)], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Thank you, in case I want to have maximum 7 player and minimum 2, would I put:
max_players= 0
while (max_players <2) or (max_players > 5) :
    max_players = int(input(" Please choose a number of players between 2 and 5.  "))
    
while len (players_dict) < max_players: 
    player = input("Enter your first and last name: ")


If yes, where sould I put it? I was thinking line 21

Comment: I modified the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! The console suggests that there is an error in line 11, in particular TypeError: Player() takes no arguments

Comment: Did you copy/paste my code, or did you type the fixes? It's probably a typo, since the code I posted works fine on my end.